# JS array to combine into one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following js array using serialisedArray -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_location_id]
            [value] => 54321
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_problem_id]
            [value] => 65432
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_priority_id]
            [value] => 76896
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => sub_maintenance_template[1][description]
            [value] => sample description
        )
)
```

Expected array -

```
[sub_maintenance_template] => Array (
    [1] =>
        (
            [maintenance_location_id]=> 54321
            [maintenance_problem_id]=> 65432
            [maintenance_priority_id]=>76896
            [description]=> sample description
        )
)
```

I tried like this-

```
foreach( $tableData as $key => $value ) {
        echo $key;
        $newArray['sub_maintenance_template'][3][] = $value['name'];
        $newArray['sub_maintenance_template'][3][] = $value['value'];
    }
```

Even though I iterate it through foreach but failed to get desired output. IS there any way to get desired one?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are tagging JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to pass these as actual arrays in GET or POST, but since the string in `name` is how arrays would be passed in a URL query string, you can use `parse_str`:

```
foreach($array as $values) {
    parse_str("{$values['name']} = {$values['value']}", $result);
}
print_r($result);
```

Or another way; extract and build key/value pairs to build a query string and then parse it:

```
parse_str(http_build_query(array_column($array, 'value', 'name')), $result);
print_r($result);
```